# Change Vertical Line and Color bar chart in bar chart.js

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, chart.js

[image]

help me ! 
 how to delete numeric data on the bar chart in bar chartjs

```
    let datas_1 = [97,70,87,43,35,18];
    let colorHex_1 = ['#ebeef3','#ebeef3','#ebeef3','#ebeef3','#ebeef3','#ebeef3'];
    let labels_1 = ['10대','12대','30대','40대','50대','60대이상'];
    var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx_1, {
        type: 'horizontalBar',
        data: {
            datasets: [{
                data: datas_1 ,
                backgroundColor: colorHex_1,
                borderWidth: 0,
                barPercentage: 1,
            }],
            labels: labels_1,
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            legend: {
                display:false,
            },
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    display:false,
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    gridLines:{
                        display:false,
                        color: "black"
                    },
                    maxBarThickness: 20,
                }]
            }
        }
    });
```

how to delete numeric data on the bar chart in bar chart.js

Comment: what is the value of  `ctx_1`

Comment: let ctx_1 = document.getElementById('chart_bar').getContext('2d');

Comment: @HiếuĐặnghữu did my answer helped ? All numeric value are gone now ?

Comment: thank you! What I want is that only the numbers in the bar will disappear, the title values ​​in front of the bars will stay the same.

Comment: You need to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). And please be clear on what is the problem is. Other wise community have to keep asking you which would make getting an answer harder.

Comment: If there is something wrong please forgive me, I'm not good at English, must use English translation tools, so there is something wrong please forgive me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/usmanmunir/hz3gLj19/3/

Try this code:

```
let datas_1 = [97,70,87,43,35,18];
let colorHex_1 = ['#ebeef3', '#ebeef3', '#ebeef3', '#ebeef3', '#ebeef3', '#ebeef3'];
let labels_1 = ['10대', '12대', '30대', '40대', '50대', '60대이상'];

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");

var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'horizontalBar',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      data: datas_1,
      backgroundColor: colorHex_1,
      borderWidth: 0,
      barPercentage: 1,
    }],
    labels: labels_1,
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    legend: {
      display: false,
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        display: false,
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          display: false,
        },
        maxBarThickness: 20,
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @HiếuĐặnghữu Can you please specifiy which digits you want you remove? Please mention all here ? Thanks. There are two type of numeric number one in the bar which starts from 97 and others are labels starting from 10대 - WHICH ONE you want to remove ?

Comment: i just want to delete 97 and keep 10 대, if you can please help me

Comment: @HiếuĐặnghữu Click here: https://jsfiddle.net/usmanmunir/t8dgjnLy/2/ all working. No 97 showing. Let me know.

Comment: @HiếuĐặnghữu vertical black bars disappeared as well as you wanted: see here: https://jsfiddle.net/usmanmunir/hz3gLj19/4/